# NSMenuDelegate methods not called for contextual menu

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenu

I have a Document based application. I want to add a contextual menu that displays context-sensitive info when the user right-clicks selected text in an NSTextView.

I have followed the advice in the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/DisplayContextMenu.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004968-SW1) and

- Added an NSMenu as a root object in my XIB file.
- Connected the NSMenu instance to the `menu` outlet of the NSTextView.
- Connected an IBAction to the NSMenuItem inside the NSMenu.

So far so good. Every thing works as expected: the menu item appears and the action is called when it is selected.

I need to get the selected text from the NSTextView before the menu appears so that I can configure my menu item appropriately. According to the docs

> If you need to customize the contextual menu, you can do so by setting
>   an appropriate object as the menu’s delegate and implementing the
>   menuWillOpen: method to customize the menu as you see fit just before
>   it appears.

I connect the delegate of the NSMenu to File's Owner. None of the delegate methods are called. ( `menuWillOpen:` is the only one I need, but I've tried others, too).

I set a breakpoint inside the IBAction that gets called when the menu item is selected. If I inspect the menu with the debugger I can see that the delegate is correctly set to the object that implements the delegate method.

Is there anything else to check? Anything I'm doing blatantly wrong?

Xcode v4.6.3
SDK v10.8
Deployment target 10.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging, this is what I found: `NSTextView` builds a different `NSMenu` instance to use as the contextual menu, probably by overriding `-menuForEvent:` or some similar internal method. This new menu copies the menu items from the menu you created in Interface Builder (in fact, it creates new menu item instances whose attributes are copied from the original menu items) but it does not copy the menu delegate, which is why your menu delegate does not receive `-menuWillOpen:`. I am not sure whether this is intentional or not. Reading that documentation quote you posted, it seems to be a bug.

What you can do is to set the delegate of your `NSTextView` instance to an object whose class conforms to `NSTextViewDelegate` (maybe your File’s Owner, which already conforms to `NSMenuDelegate`) and implement the following method:

```
- (NSMenu *)textView:(NSTextView *)view menu:(NSMenu *)menu forEvent:(NSEvent *)event atIndex:(NSUInteger)charIndex
{
    // if the menu delegate is not self, set another object
    [menu setDelegate:self];

    return menu;
}
```

This will make sure that the contextual menu created by the text view uses your delegate.

NB: since `NSTextView` creates a different contextual menu, it *could* be the case that it might want to set the menu delegate to itself or some other internal object. In my tests the delegate is `nil`, so it looks like it’s safe. Alternatively, you could discard the proposed `menu` argument and return your own `NSMenu` instance with the delegate correctly set.

Comment: Bravo! Setting the delegate as you suggest seems to work, but I don't even have to. The NSTextViewDelegate call you point out gives me access to the text view and the menu, which is everything I need to customize the menu to my needs. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finding this thread saved me a lot of time...thanks! Here's an implementation that works in an `NSView` in Swift. `myNSMenu` is an outlet from Storyboard to `appDelegate` and a subclass of `NSMenu`. Without the assignment of the delegate in the code below, the `NSMenuDelegate` functions were not called.

```
    let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.myNSMenu.delegate = appDelegate.myNSMenu
    NSMenu.popUpContextMenu(appDelegate.myNSMenu, withEvent: theEvent, forView: self)
```