# Key Modifiers monitor not called during contextual menu

Tags: swift, macos, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

Regarding: [NSMenuDelegate methods not called for contextual menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990726/nsmenudelegate-methods-not-called-for-contextual-menu/16991656#16991656) my delegate for a view isn't called once it's visible.

`newWindowMenuItem`'s title I'd like to dynamically toggle depending on a key modifier.

```
func menuWillOpen(_ menu: NSMenu) {
    guard newWindowMenuItem.title != "close" else {
        return
    }
    newWindowMenuItem.title = (appDelegate.shiftKeyDown) ? "Tab" : "Window"
    menu.update()
}

func menuDidClose(_ menu: NSMenu) {
    if menu == newWindowMenuItem.menu {
        newWindowMenuItem.title = "closed"
    }
}

func menu(_ menu: NSMenu, willHighlight item: NSMenuItem?) {
    if let currentEvent = NSApp.currentEvent, item == newWindowMenuItem {
        let flags = currentEvent.modifierFlags
        newWindowMenuItem.title = (flags.contains(.command)) ? "Tab" : "Window"
        menu.update()
        Swift.print("title \(newWindowMenuItem.title)")
    }
}
```

Registered in viewDidLoad() as

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(WebViewController.shiftKeyDown(_:)),
    name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "shiftKeyDown"),
    object: nil)
```

I'm trying to allow a user to dynamically alter menu items - titles mostly, when a modifier is pressed.  As this happens after the menu is draw, using menuWillOpen() does not seem to be viable, as otherwise they could press a modifier - other than CTRL before it's drawn.

I was thinking to skip the delegate altogether - as I'm not reading a suitable method for key modifier changes for my needs, and instead, have a key monitor affect the changes:

```
internal func shiftKeyDown(_ notification : Notification) {
    let shiftKeyDown : NSNumber = notification.object as! NSNumber
    Swift.print(String(format: "shift %@", shiftKeyDown.boolValue ? "v" : "^"))

    guard webView.menu != nil else {
        return
    }
    newWindowMenuItem.title = shiftKeyDown.boolValue ? "Tab" : "Window"
    newWindowMenuItem.menu?.update()
}
```

but this is never called or the key event, post menu display suggesting my approach is wrong?

Comment: Is this something that can simply be achieved using menu alternates?

Comment: Yeah; over thinking this within context of other things.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't register your notification handler properly. The method

```
internal func shiftKeyDown(_ notification : Notification)
```

has no chance to be ever called, because it is not marked as `@objc`. It should be written

```
@objc internal func shiftKeyDown(_ notification : Notification)
```

You may have another `shiftKeyDown` method somewhere that does actually get called, or your registration code is not working at all. (Or you have a similar named method somewhere and you have a typo somewhere.)

(`NotificationCenter` is still just a fancy Swift name for the Objective C `NSNotificationCenter`, which in turn is based on the even older CFNotificationCenter. And the whole `#selector`-feature of Swift is built on top of the objc-runtime, so it only works with objc-methods.)

Comment: No joy; if the menu isn't active, I get notifications or without @objc but I'll leave it in as you describe, thanks.  Once the contextual menu is active, I cannot get new events.  If the modifier *is* present at the view's willOpenMenu(:,event:) call, then it works to affect the title, but it's not dynamic; once the modifier key is released the state change isn't notified.

Comment: @slashlos: how do you register for the notification? Are you using the [NotificationCenter.addObserver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1415360-addobserver) method anywhere?

Comment: Yes; I altered the question to include the registration. It doesn't seem to differ in results if I include the full selector: WebViewController.shiftKeyDown or just shiftKeyDown.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael had the right idea; I loathe keys on contextual menus which led me here but simple works too!  Building item/alternate in contextual menu

```
    item = NSMenuItem(title: "Window", action: #selector(appDelegate.newDocument(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
    item.target = appDelegate
    subOpen.addItem(item)

    item = NSMenuItem(title: "Tab", action: #selector(appDelegate.newDocument(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
    item.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .shift
    item.target = appDelegate
    item.isAlternate = true
    item.tag = 1
    subOpen.addItem(item)
```